# Querying a hash in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, mongoid

I have created a product document that looks as follows:

```
#<Product _id: 539ac4285468691170000000, created_at: 2014-06-13 09:28:08 UTC, updated_at: 2014-06-13 10:28:57 UTC, properties: {"first"=>{"element_1"=>"test", "element_2"=>"bigtest"}, "second"=>"layer_one"}>
```

Now I have read a lot about querying using `where()`. Yet I have not found any information whether it is possible and if yes how to extract individual elements of a **hash**.

How can I query something like this:

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 > w = Product.last
ruby 2.0.0p451 > w.properties.first
ruby 2.0.0p451 > w.properties.first.element_2
ruby 2.0.0p451 > w.properties.first.push("element_3"=>"grandetest")
```

Can you please point to a reference where I could see more Mongoid querying examples and in particular to such ones that extract individual components of a hash. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to access to hash values:

```
> w.properties['first']
=> {"element_1"=>"test", "element_2"=>"bigtest"}

> w.properties['first']['element_2']
=> "bigtest"

> w.properties['first']['element_3'] = "grandetest"
=> {"element_1"=>"test", "element_2"=>"bigtest", "element_3"=>"grandetest"}
```

You can use 'where' to search a Product by a value of 'element_2' for example:

```
> Product.where("properties.first.element_2" => "bigtest").count
=> 1
```

I hope you will be helpful.

Comment: I like your answer very much. In the meantime I was able to figure out a less convenient way:
`> w.properties.__nested__('first.element_2')
=> "bigtest"`